# Can an ndjson file be saved using xdmp.save?

Tags: json, marklogic, marklogic-9

I have a requirement to gather certain JSON documents from my database and save them in an outside drive as one file for a downstream consumer.

Using server-side Javascript I can combine the documents in a JSON object or array. However, they need to be saved into this singular file in ndjson format.

Is there any way to do this using `xdmp.save` in MarkLogic? I thought of saving the documents as a sequence but that throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

[`xdmp.save()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.save) expects a `node()` for the second parameter.

You could serialize the JSON docs and delimit with a carriage return to generate the [Newline Delimited JSON](http://ndjson.org/), and then create a `text()` node from that string.

```
const ndjson = new NodeBuilder()
  .addText(cts.search(cts.collectionQuery("json")).toArray().join("\n"))
  .toNode();
xdmp.save("/temp/ndjson.json", ndjson);
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have added in my post that I have to do various transformations to each document as well before outputting it to the file system. Therefore I make my own array with the transformed documents.
/*Code to create array called variable createdArray*/
const ndjson = new NodeBuilder()
  .addText(createdArray.join("\n"))
  .toNode()
The ndjson variable then comes out to [Object object]. Can you help me understand why?

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted the code that you were applying, but I suspect that the Object is not being serialized as a string. When you are adding items to your `createdArray`, try using `JSON.stringify()` i.e. `createdArray.push(JSON.stringify(item));`